# UIScrollView bounces back to top

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, swift3

Inside a `UIScrollView` I have Container `UIView` that is larger than screen and when I scroll even a little it automatically bounces back to top after I release it.

I have set margins of Container `UIView` and `UIScrollView` to 0 and add the constraints `Equal Height` and `Equal Width` to Container `UIView` in relation to the Main `UIView`.

I saw that many people asked similar question but none of answers to their question helped me.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you constraints correct? You can also manually set the contentSize of the scrollview = to the size of the frame of the containerView in viewDidLayoutSubviews but thats super hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your constraints are appropriate. As you have already mentioned that the container view's height is greater than the screen (also greater than the scroll view), you can try setting the contentSize of the ScrollView manually in viewDidLayoutSubViews.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.containerView.size;
}
```

If it does not work, then try using the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
}
```